# How to solve Python error: usb descriptors

Tags: python, google-chrome, scripting, anaconda

As the title says I'm receiving an error when importing a python script.[When importing script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW1P4.png) I would normally import the script then run it but it does not appear to run. I assume all my path and libraries are up to date but I could be wrong. Any suggestion would be helpful[When attempting to run the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6vkc.png)

I've tried updated chrome drivers, USB drivers, reinstalling python/anaconda, setting up environment variables

Comment: I personally don't click on links so I'm not sure what it is you're sharing there but could you elaborate a little on what you mean by importing a python script? Do you mean importing/installing to your computer to run or do you mean importing it as a module for another python instance/script ?

Comment: Thats fair. looks like I'm unable to until 10 rep points.

Ill try to explain better. I use a script to run through a series of in-browser (google chrome) decisions. While having the python prompt open I use import "script name" to open the browser and  "script name".run to run the script although for both of these processes it appears I'm getting an error. Another reference I could find online say this error shouldn't stop the script from running but I'm not sure what is keeping the script from running

Comment: Do you know where the script is installed on your machine? And/or are you able to open it up and read it? If it's refusing to behave and you can read it, you could always paste it into a python instance directly and see if it spits out any errors